# Moving many files from a listview selection to another directory in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, io, windows-explorer

My application should function like Windows Explorer whereby you can select many items from a `listview` and then drag and drop to another directory in a `treeview`.

The issue is when I am attempting to transfer lots of files from the selection in the `listview` (let say 1000 files selected), the application freezes and only a couple of files get successfully transferred. however it doesn't have any issue moving small amounts of files at a time.

Here is a snippet of my code where it loops through the selected list items and move them:

```
var lvi = (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection");

foreach(ListViewItem item in lvi)
{
 var originPathObj = item.Tag;
 var originPathFileType = item.SubItems[1].Text;

 if(originPathFileType == "File")
 {
     var originDirInfo = (FileInfo)originPathObj;

     string originPath = originDirInfo.FullName;
     string originFileName = originDirInfo.Name;

     var destinationDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)dn.Tag;
     string destinationPath = destinationDirInfo.FullName;
     string destinationPathWithFile = destinationPath + "\\" + originFileName;

        if (File.Exists(originPath) && Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
        {
             FileSystem.MoveFile(originPath, destinationPathWithFile, UIOption.AllDialogs);
        }
 }
}
```

Does anyone know a better way where I can successfully move the files? I have searched online and all that I found were people suggesting what I have already done which is the `File.Move` code in a `foreach` loop.

Also, the `FileSystem.MoveFile(originPath, destinationPathWithFile, UIOption.AllDialogs);` already provides a dialog with the progress bar when moving files. But when moving small amounts of files, the results are instant and when moving the 1000 files in Windows Explorer, the progress bar appears for a brief moment which is something I also want to achieve in my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Task.Run(() =>
 {
    YourLongRunningFunc();
 });
```

Just put all your logic in your post in the YourLongRunningFunc(). This makes your UI responsive and no frozen UI will be noticeable.

Comment: I have since moved the logic inside of the foreach loop from my original post into a task and starting them concurrently. The good news is that now the progress bar appears and I know that files are transferring but the bad news is that Many running actions are created so, the dialog actually has many progress bars each saying "Moving 1 item from X to Y" Is there anyway where I can consolidate all the files that I'm moving before combining them into one progress bar just like what File Explorer does? I want the progress bar to show like "Moving 700 items from X to Y"

Comment: You can do it on your own and create your own progress bar, for sure. It only a matter of complexity.